# get post request in magento 2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect

I have created one event listing page, I am trying to when I click any event from event list it will redirect to appropriate event detail page.

[image: For your easy reference]

I can able to done by using ajax method, but I am looking for magento way to done this.

I have a plan to collect appropriate event details by using **event name and date**, but I don't know how to pass the value using get or post in magento 2 when click event.

I hope I am clear, still need any additional notes please mention in comment.

Thanks

Comment: you want to pass some value from view.phtml to controller/block correct??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do you want to send the value only by get/post.
you can use parameter method in to get the data as below:

**In Action Controller or Block:**

```
$value = $this->getRequest()->getParam('parameter');
```

Where `'parameter'` you get from url as below:

```
http://localhost/frontname/controllerfolder/controllername/parameter/value/
```

if your value is not that sensitive then you can use above method, if you want use post method only then u need to use script or print all the link in form.

Hope this will help you..

Comment: Thanks dude, I have already done, but the difference between you and me is I have pass value like "`http://url?parameter=value`", When I follow your way its shows 404 not found, which is right way

Comment: its working, both way is possible to pass the value . I think your way is the right one it seems like magento way.